# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gs', '-q', ...] returned non-zero exit status 2

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, discord.py, python-imaging-library, ghostscript

(My operating system is macOS)

I am making a discord bot which allows a user to create graphics and display using an image through python's `turtle` module.

After creating the graphics I post-script the canvas to my desktop as an `eps` file with the user's username in the filename:

```
import turtle

...

Canvas = turtle.Screen()
Canvas.getcanvas().postscript(file=f"desktop/{context.author}'s_graphics.eps")
```

I attempted to output it as an `eps` file knowing that it wouldn't work but still worth a try:

```
import discord

...

await context.send(
    embed=discord.Embed().set_image(url="attachment://graphics.png"),
    file=discord.File(f"desktop/{context.author}'s_graphics.png","graphics.png")
)
```

But as expected it didn't work.

So I tried to directly convert it to a `png` file, if I were to do that by hand the file would become unreadable and if I convert it back to `eps` it would be readable again.

So then I used the `PIL` module to convert the `eps` file to `png`:

```
import turtle
from PIL import Image

...

Canvas = turtle.Screen()
Canvas.getcanvas().postscript(file=f"desktop/{context.author}'s_graphics.eps")
image=Image.open(f"desktop/{context.author}'s_graphics.eps") # Where macOS terminal error was raised
image.convert("RGBA") # Where Visual Studio Code error was raised
```

I had a few errors involving `ghostscript` being the root of the problem, I resolved them by installing `ghostscript` using `homebrew` because I didn't have it installed beforehand apparently.

But now I get two separate errors in two different command lines

If I were to run the script in the macOS terminal (and call the command in discord) I would get this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "desktop/Bossman#4404's_graphics.eps"` - fair enough I can just get the absolute path or something. <- This error was raised

However, if I run the script in the `Visual Studio Code` terminal I get this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gs', '-q', '-g719x675', '-r72.000000x72.000000', '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dSAFER', '-sDEVICE=ppmraw', '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/ms/wv_n3bzs7zvctx07pqqzv__m0000gp/T/tmpg65g140v', '-c', '53 -59 translate', '-f', "desktop/Bossman#4404's_graphics.eps", '-c', 'showpage']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

I think it involves `ghostscript` again based off of the `gs` being an element in the array in the exception.

I went over several stackoverflow posts on this similar exception but in all of those posts they were directly using the `subprocess` module where I am not so Im not sure what to do.

How do I fix this? Or simply just make an `eps` to `png` file conversion?

Any other help would also be appreciated. <3

## Edit:

Just to clarify I am not using turtle `mainloop()` or `update()` since I'm already running a loop being `client.run(TOKEN)` and I can't run simultaneous loops to my knowledge. (The discord loop is to run async functions.)

(Even removing `image.convert("RGBA")` I still get the same error at `image.save()`)

I've just noticed at the very top of the exception it says:

```
Usage: gs [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'gs --help' for help.

Error: no such option: -q
```

Then comes in the

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

### Code Edit:

```
import turtle
from PIL import Image
from os import system, path

...

directory = f"Users/family/Desktop/{context.author}'s_graphics"

Canvas = turtle.Screen()
Canvas.getcanvas().postscript(file=directory+".eps")
image = Image.open(path.realpath(directory+".eps"))
image.convert("RGBA") # Where error is raised
image.save(directory+".png",lossless=True)
await context.send(
    embed=embed("").set_image(url="attachment://graphics.png"),
    file=discord.File(directory+".png","graphics.png")
)
system(f"rm {directory}.png")
```

Comment: `desktop/whatever` is not an absolute pathname - it's relative to the current working directory, wherever that might be.  Ghostscript is apparently being run with a different working directory than your program, making this a *meaningless* pathname to pass to it.  You need to use an absolute pathname here.

Comment: Try running Ghostscript from the command shell using the same parameters. Does it work  ? If not, what does it say ? If it does work then it's something to do with the environment (paths, current working directory etc) If it doesn't then you've now got more information to report (you probably want to drop -q for this too). As to 'an eps to png file conversion' that's always going to require you to use a PostScript interpreter, because PostScript is a programming language.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @jasonharper I gave absolute paths using `os.path.abspath()` and I still get the same errors

Comment: @KenS If I type `gs` alone in the command line no error is raised and I receive an output of its version, options, commands etc. I also ran it with the same parameters and left out `-q` as you said and it just gave me `quote>` with whatever inputted nothing happens. The problem could be that I don't have a PostScript interpreter, how can I check? And if not how can I download it?

Comment: By 'quote>' do you actually mean 'GS>' ? That's the interactive PostScript interpreter. Given that, and the fact that you got the help message, the problem seems to be that you haven't given Ghostscript a file to operate on, which fits with the 'no such file or directory'. So as jasonharper said (or at least implied) that's your problem. When you say you supplied an absolute path, what did you actually give as the path name ? I would guess that what's on the desktop isn't a real file, its a symlink to the actual file location. You need to find out what that is, try realpath() ?

Comment: @KenS Im not sure what `quote>` means to be honest, printing the absolute path of the desktop gives me `/Users/family/desktop` (family being the user account) and if I manually check the absolute path of the desktop it also shows that. Printing the realpath of the desktop also gives the same output. Im not even sure whether to run the script from my IDE or mac terminal, typically the terminal is better but the IDE seems to get past the postscript function while the terminal cannot. I applied `realpath()` and I still get that ghostscript error except now its in both the IDE and mac terminal

Comment: Ill update the post to show the new code.

Comment: Please try to simplify what you are actually trying to do and what the problem is... at the moment you are talking about discord bots and turtles, users and desktops, EPS and PNG, Python and ghostscript, files and PIL and Visual Studio... thank you.

Comment: Well the absolute path sounds right. I don't know where quote> is coming from. Starting Ghostscript on it's own from the command line should just give you a "GS>" prompt. In order to get the options and devices etc, you would need to add --help, or have a startup error. -q is supposed (IIRC) to be the same as -dQUIET, you could try using that instead.

Comment: Apologies @MarkSetchell, I have simplified and specified to the best of my ability, If you read it all through without skipping a part then it'd all make sense

Comment: @KenS If I run just `gs` by itself in my terminal it gives an output with commands and options as said before, and says: `Run "gs COMMAND --help" for command-specific usage and options.` If I do so it says: `no such command "COMMAND" try "gs --help"` and if I do so it outputs  what it would output if I just put `gs` by itself. And actually, looking at it I don't think this `gs` command is even `ghostscript` as it says: `gs is a minimalistic CLI for Google Cloud Storage` and looking at the commands it seems that "gs" stands for: "Google Storage". What on earth is going on

Comment: ^ Overall, it doesn't prompt me

Comment: Well that doesn't sound like Ghostscript, certainly. If you just execute the Ghostscript executable I'd expect you to get a Copyright messge like "GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0 (2021 -03-30)" followed by a couple more lines of boiler plate copyright/licence and then a "GS>" prompt. You will probably need to find where you installed Ghostscript, and supply a complete path to the executable in order to test your Python. I suspect you will probably also need to reconfigure your python environment, PATH etc in order to locate the Ghostscript GS executable.....

Comment: @KenS Ive located the ghostscript folder which inside is a folder named `9.54.0` which has a bin, include, lib and share folders which in them I suppose you can guess. Running the executable named `gs` found in bin does exactly what you said. How do I reconfigure everything so that ghostscript works. For the gs command to work I think it must be in my $PATH environment variable but it probably isn't there because the google cloud storage replaces the command prefix? The ghostscript folder is located in `/usr/local/cellar`

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't a clue. I don't run on macOS and don't use Python. My guess is that the Ghostscript path is in your &PATH, but **after** the Google utility, so that gets found first, but I can't be sure. You could try reordering the entries in $PATH or removing the Google one (though that may of course cause other problems). Other than that you would need to find where in the Python environment runs gs and replace 'gs' with a fully qualified path.Oh, you could also rename the Google binary if you don't need it, that might work.

Comment: No worries and thank you because you sir / madam @KenS have helped me greatly thus my high appreciations go your way.